# 'No healthy upstream' error when Envoy proxy is set up manually

Tags: docker-compose, envoyproxy

I have a very simple environment with a client, a server and an envoy proxy, each running on a separate docker, communicating over http.
When I set it using docker-compose it works.
However, when I set up the dockers and the network manually (with `docker network create`, setting the aliases, etc.), I get a "503 - no healthy upstream" message when the client tries to send requests to the server. curl to the network alias works from the envoy container. Any idea what is the difference between using docker-compose and setting up the network and containers manually?

envoy.yaml:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 10000
      filter_chains:
          - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: backend
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/" }
                          route: { cluster: service }
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config: {}
  clusters:
    - name: service
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: STRICT_DNS
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: service
        endpoints:
        - lb_endpoints:
          - endpoint:
              address:
                socket_address:
                  address: server-stub
                  port_value: 5000
admin:
  access_log_path: "/tmp/envoy.log"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9901
```

The docker-compose file that worked (but I don't want to use docker-compose, I am using scripts that set up each docker separately):

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  envoy:
    image: envoyproxy/envoy:v1.16-latest
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
      - "9901:9901"
    volumes:
      - ./envoy.yaml:/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml

  server-stub:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
```

Comment: Can you share your compose file?

Comment: I have update the question with the docker compose, though I don't want to use it, I have scripts to set up the dockers with many other configuration, I need to use those to set up every docker separately and then connect them on a netwrok.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this. It works fine with your docker-compose file, and it works fine manually. Here are the manual steps I took:

```
$ docker network create test-net
$ docker container run --network test-net --name envoy -p 10000:10000 -p 9901:9901 --mount type=bind,src=/home/john/projects/tester/envoy.yaml,dst=/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml envoyproxy/envoy:v1.16-latest
$ docker run --network test-net --name server-stub johnharris85/simple-hostname-reporter:3
```

My sample app also listens on port 5000. I used your exact envoy config. Using Docker 20.10.8 if relevant.

Comment: Thanks! it did help. the difference between what you did and what I did is that I first created the envoy container and then connected it to the network. So following your example I ran it directly with `--network` parameter, and it works now!